# Jekyll get Attributes of Collection Element instead of Output

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection of elements that have output on `true`. Now I'd like to make an array of some of those Collection elements, but only its attributes and not the output. However, if I use `{{ assign arr = arr | push: site.col['elem'] }}` it doesn't work, as this gives me the output.

Alternatively, I tried `{{ assign arr = arr | push: [site.col['elem'].attr1, site.col['elem'].attr1] }}` but this gave me the following Liquid Error:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 86): wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) in (PATH)

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push only accepts 2 arguments. You can use a for loop and add desired attributes to a hash.

The code checks if the output attribute of a collection is true and extracts the desired attributes into a new object called elem_attributes before pushing it to the result array:

```
{% assign arr = [] %}
{% for elem in site.col %}
    {% if elem.output == true %}
    {% assign elem_attributes = { 'attr1': elem.attr1 } %}
    {% assign arr = arr | push: elem_attributes %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope I got you right.